# Simple tail-call optimization for recursive, while-loop style functions

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function:

```
const stackOverflow = (n = 0) =>
  n === 10000 ? 'cool' : stackOverflow(n + 1)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dsso9pg6/

When I run this, I hit a **"Maximum call stack size exceeded"** error.  I've read that these sorts of recursive functions can be written differently to avoid this issue in the call stack (something to do with "tail-call optimization"...), but I don't quite see where the issue lies.

How would I keep this same recursive function structure while avoiding the error?

Edit:  Or is this already tail-call optimized?  (I was seeing the error in Node.js 8.6 and Chrome 61, but Safari 11 doesn't complain and returns "Cool.")

Comment: _"When I run this, I hit a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error."_ Cannot reproduce

Comment: You might have to check your console for the log error.  (I'm in Chrome 61)

Comment: Please be aware that most browsers don't implement TCO: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-proper_tail_calls_(tail_call_optimisation) .

Comment: @FelixKling Oh wow, that's red across the board even into Node.js.  Hmm.

Comment: No error was logged at Chromium 61

Comment: @guest271314 in Node.js 8.6 I get "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it right, the while-loop in procedural programming can be replaced by recursion in functional programming paradigm. Hence, a technique called "tail-call optimization" is invented in some functional programming languages (Haskell for example) to deal with long call stacks in these scenarios.

The maximum call stack in javascript also depends on the runtime environment: for example, it's 30000 in my browser but could this could vary. So your code works fine in my browser and not throw an error. But the idea is that there is an upper limit and tail-call optimization could eliminate that.

However, tail-call optimization is a feature supported on language engine level and works in the background rather than a feature that we can use. And unfortunately, javascript is not truly an FP language so it does not support this feature yet. Hopefully, when ES6 is finalized we can have this cool feature and use functional programming to its full extent.

Edit: You can check whether your runtime environment support TCO here (look like Safari already supported it)

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: ES6 was finalized two years ago in 2015.

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry I mean it (TCO) is not widely supported yet

Comment: What do I need to watch out for in my code to ensure that tail call optimization can be performed by the JS engine?   I came across a few long articles on TCO, but I was having trouble really seeing the change in structure that would allow or prevent this from happening (something to do with avoiding certain variables in the function's return statement?)

Comment: The simple question is no, there is nothing you can do about it. TCO is simply not widely adopted yet. In the meantime, stick to while-loop if you have feeling that a recursive function could blow the call stack.

Comment: @arby The point is that a function must directly `return` the result of the recursive call, with no further operations after the call. Your `stackOverflow` function does that already.